# Android Studio displays device as "offline" with deviceSDK(API 1)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, nexus-5

I have a Nexus 5 which I have been using for Android development for the last few months. I had no issues except for maybe a minor driver issue when I first got the phone. Recently I switched from the USB cable I received with the device, to a cable from a 3rd party vendor which is supposedly made to be compatible with the Nexus 5. I'm not sure why, but I am having a lot of trouble getting my device to work as a debugging device with Android Studio with this new cable.

First, after plugging the USB cable into the same USB port which I was using with the original cable, Windows was completely unable to recognize the device. I tried messing around with some of the drivers, before I gave up and went back to my old cable.

Today I tried using the new cable again, on a different USB port and the drivers seem to install correctly for the Nexus 5. I can browse my files on my Windows 8.1 fine now. But in Android Studio when I try to run a project on the device, I am unable to do so because the device is listed as "OFFLINE" and with deviceSDK(API 1).

[image: Device selection dialog]

When I attempt to select this entry and run the app, nothing happens on the device, but Android Studio does not report any issues. Anyone have any idea what the issue might be? I literally cannot find anyone with the same issue anywhere.

EDIT: Link to the cable in question, if this helps. Not sure how any data cable could be different from another. http://www.shopandroid.com/ventev-6ft-micro-usb-charging-data-cable/5A18A18302A.htm

Comment: Is it any help if you go to developer options on your phone settings - then disable and re-enable usb debugging?

Comment: Nope, have tried that. Tried disabling and enabling MTP as well, no go.

Comment: Does it get listed when you use `adb devices` from the command line?

Comment: Does it work with the original cable? If so, then problem solved.

Comment: @free3dom Nope, nothing is displayed when trying `adb devices`. And @ScottBarta, I would like this new cable to work as I am actually borrowing the original Nexus 5 cable from a friend.

Comment: Try updating your drivers: [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) or [here](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver).

Comment: @free3dom: I get the same error on Linux, using a bleeding edge kernel, so I don't think that's the problem.